# Calculate % improvement from pre and post test (MYSQL & PHP)

Tags: php, mysql

Here is a link to this setup in SQLFiddle - http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/b652d/1

I want to find all the students who did both a pre and a post test.  I then want to get an overall percent change from the pretest to the post test.

Here is my query which is not returning any result for the post test:

```
 SELECT studid, TestDate, pre, post, ROUND( (
( post - pre ) / pre ) *100, 1 ) AS percentChange
FROM bodpod
WHERE ID2 =  'fall'
AND studid !=  ''
GROUP BY studid
HAVING COUNT( DISTINCT ID1 ) >1
AND TestDate LIKE  '%2013%'
```

Here is sample data for one student:
[image: Sample data for one student]

How can I rewrite that query to get the desired results which is an overall percent change for all students that took the pre AND the post test in the fall of 2013?

Comment: consider provding proper DDLs and/or an sqlfiddle TOGETHER WITH THE DESIRED RESULT

Comment: So, all but 4 of those columns are irrelevant to the problem at hand?

Comment: The fiddle returns all 0s for `select post from bodpod;`

Comment: Here is an updated fiddle with the irrelevant colums removed:  http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/b652d/1

Comment: geoB, I just updated the data to have a value for post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Edit # 2:

After looking at the data in your fiddle, and guessing that the raw data are already percentages, I suggest something like this:

```
select round(sum(After)/count(After) - sum(B4)/count(B4), 2) '% Change' from
(select studid, sum(pre) 'B4' , sum(post) 'After' 
from bodpod
group by studid
having After > 0 and B4 > 0) data;
```

Corrected:

```
SELECT t1.studid, t1.TestDate, t1.pre, t2.post, ROUND( (
( t2.post - t1.pre ) / t1.pre ) *100, 1 ) AS percentChange
FROM bodpod t1
join bodpod t2 on t1.studid = t2.studid
WHERE t1.ID2 =  'fall'
AND t1.studid !=  ''
and t2.pre=0
GROUP BY studid
HAVING COUNT( DISTINCT t1.ID1 ) >1
AND TestDate LIKE  '%2013%'
```

When I run it (in MySQL Workbench) I get:

```
studid  TestDate    pre post    percentChange
6093191 8/12/2013 10:38 27.7    22.8    -17.7
```

For cumulative percentage (assumes no weighting required):

```
SELECT  ROUND( ( (sum(After) - sum(B4)) / sum(B4) ) *100, 1 ) AS percentChange from
(SELECT t1.studid, t1.TestDate, t1.pre as B4, t2.post as After
FROM bodpod t1
join bodpod t2 on t1.studid = t2.studid
WHERE t1.ID2 =  'fall'
AND t1.studid !=  ''
and t2.pre=0
GROUP BY studid
HAVING COUNT( DISTINCT t1.ID1 ) >1
AND TestDate LIKE  '%2013%') scores
```

Comment: took a while to recognize that pre & post were in different records.

Comment: Thank you geoB.  I need for there to also be the value in the pre field as well as the percentChange.  When I run the above query both of those fields are blank.  Any ideas on how to get those fields to show the appropriate values?

Comment: Not sure how that could be.  I added result of my running query (although positioning of column headers not quite right).

Comment: I ran the query on my live database and it gave the results. I'll be able to use that query for part of my project so thank you!  What I may have failed to ask correctly is how do I get the overall percent change between pre and post test?  So I need to take the average of all pretests and see the percent change to all of the posttests.  There would be one result...such as a 4% change from the pretest to the posttest for all students that took both the pre and post test.  Does that make sense?

Comment: Try replacing each `t1.pre` with `sum(t1.pre)`, `t2.post` with `sum(t2.pre)` and deletng the `group by` to get a single value.  Test on a larger sample to verify 'cuz this is off the top of my head.

Comment: Thanks for the replies everyone!  geoB, when I run your query for cumulative percentage the result is not what I expect.  For example, using this sqlfiddle (http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/5121c8/2), if I take the average of the pre test scores I get a value of 20.4%.  I get an average value of 18.67% for the post test scores.  I would expect the query to show that there was a 1.73% reduction in bodyfat.  What change do I need to make to the query to get that reslut?  Thanks in advance!  Tim

Comment: I've added Edit #2 above, which seems cleaner and assumes data are percentages already.

Comment: Thank you very much!  You saved me from pulling out ALL my hair!  Works perfectly!